# Change IIS .NET Framework Version via Command Line

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm working on a set of scripts to automate the install and configuration of IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm stumped on how to script the change IIS's default server-level .net framework version from **v2.0.50727** to **v4.0.30319**

I've mostly been using PowerShell so far (good excuse to force myself to learn it) along with the WebAdministration module to perform all of the configuration. A PowerShell solution is preferred, but not required.

Visual reference on where to change this in the IIS Manager:
[image]

Comment: I can see how to do this for a given app pool, but not for the server.  Is there a way to do this in the GUI, and that's why you're asking?  If so, could you tell me how you made that change manually?  If nothing else WMI or appcmd can do everything that can be done through the GUI.

Comment: Added screenshot on where the GUI element is. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the value in appcmd either.

Comment: So, what this controls is the default .NET framework version that a new app pool is created with?  If that's the case, could you try to change the default app pool's framework to .NET 4, and then create a new app pool?  Another test would be to check the current framework version on the default app pool, click that button when the main server node is selected, and then check the version on the default app pool again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command from the cmd.exe prompt to change the IIS 7 setting.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /commit:apphost
```